# struct and rand()

Tags: c

I have a struct with an array of 100 int (b) and a variable of type int (a)

I have a function that checks if the value of "a" is in the array and i have generated the array elements and the variable with random values.

but it doesn't work
can someone help me fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b[100];
} h;

int func(h v){
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(v.b[i]==v.a) 
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    h str;
    srand(time(0)); 
    int i;
    for(i=0;0<100;i++){
        str.b[i]=(rand() % 10) + 1;
    }
    str.a=(rand() % 10) + 1;
    str.a=1;

    printf("%d\n",func(str));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your check function returns after the first loop iteration. So unless the value you're looking for is the first element of the array, it returns 0 and never checks the rest of the array. The 'return 0' needs to be outside the body of the loop

```
for (i=0;i<100;i++){
    if(v.b[i]==v.a) 
        return 1;
}
return 0;
```

Additionally, the for loop in main() checks to see if 0<100 (which will pretty much always be true...)

```
for(i=0;0<100;i++){
    str.b[i]=(rand() % 10) + 1;
}
```

Should be:

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    str.b[i]=(rand() % 10) + 1;
}
```

Comment: I have another problem ... I get no output

Answer (score 0):

Your loop:

```
  for (i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(v.b[i]==v.a) 
        return 1;
        else 
        return 0;   
    }
```

should be:

```
  for (i=0;i<100;i++){
        if(v.b[i]==v.a) 
            return 1;
    }
  return 0;
```

so that you only fail after you have examined all the array entries. You might also want to pass your struct to the function using  a pointer, to avoid the copying overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the else condition in the loop in func. Unless the item you are looking for is in the first position, it will never find it.